# Magick++ Convert JPEG from CMYK to RGB Colorspace

Tags: c++, imagemagick, cmyk, magick++

I use the ImageMagick Magick++ API to work with images in my C++ program. It reads images out of PDF files. There are some Images that have a CMYK colorspace. How can I convert such images to RGB correctly?

Comment: See here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now. I used the `image->channel(AllChannels)` method. The colors are not exactly the same as before, but it is usable.

Comment: *'colors are not exactly the same as before'* -- That's the usual thing if you convert colorspaces. To minimize the effect (you can never completely eliminate it!), you'll have to use *ICC color profiles*. But that's an art in itself (and you need to have correct color profiles, which are adapted to your situation). Don't assume a simply addition of `-colorspace this +colorspace that` will magickally solve all deviations. To work with exact color fidelity, you'll have to start calibrating your monitor...